# CakePHP and conditions

Tags: php, cakephp

So in my controller `MenuController.php` I have the following code:

```
class MenuController extends AppController {

     public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

     public function index() {

        $this->set('menus', $this->Menu->find('all'));

        $userSpecific = $this->Menu->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('Menu.user_id' => '20')
        ));
     }

}
```

and in my view, I am doing the following:

```
<?php foreach ($menus as $menu): ?>

    <?php echo $menu['Menu']['id']; ?>
    <?php echo $menu['Menu']['user_id']; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

*update*

To better understand this in my browser I changed my view to the following:

```
<?php foreach ($menus as $menu): ?>

<p>Menu id <?php echo $menu['Menu']['id']; ?> is for user: <?php echo $menu['Menu']['user_id']; ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

*end update*

Now in the view, it is currently using the `$this` and returning all values from the database table, How do I change the view to use `$userSpecific` rather than `$this` I managed to get this far (making the `$userSpecific` part) by using the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list) but I could only find the controller side and not the view side. I'm sorry if it's a bad question, just trying to learn.

Comment: What do you mean by $userSpecific and $this, I am not getting your point, pls explain little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the data to the view from the controller at the end of the index() function.

You can do it like this:

```
$this->set('userSpecific', $userSpecific);
```

or like this (my preferred way)

```
$this->set(compact('userSpecific');
```

Once you've done this, you can then modify your view to show the user specific fields as shown:

```
<?php foreach ($userSpecific as $menu): ?>

    <?php echo $menu['Menu']['id']; ?>
    <?php echo $menu['Menu']['user_id']; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I will accept this answer as soon as I can. I would like to know the difference between the first and second options for your answer? Trying to learn here.

Comment: If you've only got one variable that you're sending, then they're pretty much equivalent.  Where it shines is when you're sending lots of different variables to the view, eg: $this->set(compact( 'menus', 'userSpecific', 'userDetails', 'callToAction'));

Comment: Oh that's cool. Thank you for your help! I think I'm really going to like CakePHP